# How can I avoid to do a lot of if's in java ?

Tags: java, c++

In c++, I would use a map of int/pointer to function like this :

```
std::map = {
{Code::Value1, Handler::value1Handler},
{Code::Value2, Handler::value2Handler},
};
```

To avoid to do a lot of if's like

```
if (value == Code::Value1)
  value1Handler();
if (value == Code::Value2)
  value2Handler();
if (value == Code::Value3)
  value3Handler();
```

But I didn't find a good way to do this in Java, is it possible ?

Comment: switch case?...

Comment: @FastSnail I don't like switches cases... I don't think it's very clean

Comment: If you want to execute certain methods based on an input, then I'm thinking the command pattern might be what you have in mind.

Comment: Java has maps: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: @DimitriDanilov you can put objects in it and call methods on those objects

Comment: @AndrewTobilko `::` is the scope operator for namespaces.

Comment: in what way `switch` is not clean? It may be much faster than a map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I realised, you want to associate a key `T` with a corresponding action `Consumer<T>` (or a `Function<K, V>` if a return type matters).

Unfortunately, we don't have a map literal, so for short it's possible to generate a `HashMap` subclass with a init block:

```
Map<T, Consumer<T>> map = new HashMap<T, Consumer<T>>() {{
    put(k1, v -> {/* value handler 1 */});
    put(k2, v -> {/* value handler 2 */});
}};
```

As a map value, you can pass an action which you want to perform with a key. For instance,

```
v -> System.out.println(v)
```

If such an action is single, it can be replaced by a method reference:

```
System.out::println
```

---

*(Here I comprehended that `valueXHandler`s return a map value, they aren't just consumers. Therefore, `Function<K, V>` is our way)*

Normally, I would write a mapper which transforms a key to a value and returns that value:

```
public <K, V> V mapToValue(K key, Function<K, V> function) {
    return function.apply(key);
}
```

Its usage is simple enough:

```
map.put(k1, mapToValue(k1, k1 -> v1));
```

Comment: Guava and other libraries have convenient builders for maps, which would make this example neat.

Answer (score 3):

One good (and most of the times, the right) solution is to use polymorphism. Use an abstract class (or an interface) that has many children with different implementations of the required action (the relevant function). 
Then, having a factory function that returns (or generates) the appropriate object type according to the value, and running its action function.

This might not be the right solution for a very small programs, but when dealing with real projects, this is a very good practice (and is implemented in design patterns such as State, Strategy and others).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with using switch: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

```
public class SwitchDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int month = 8;
        String monthString;
        switch (month) {
            case 1:  monthString = "January";
                     break;
            case 2:  monthString = "February";
                     break;
            case 3:  monthString = "March";
                     break;
            case 4:  monthString = "April";
                     break;
            case 5:  monthString = "May";
                     break;
            case 6:  monthString = "June";
                     break;
            case 7:  monthString = "July";
                     break;
            case 8:  monthString = "August";
                     break;
            case 9:  monthString = "September";
                     break;
            case 10: monthString = "October";
                     break;
            case 11: monthString = "November";
                     break;
            case 12: monthString = "December";
                     break;
            default: monthString = "Invalid month";
                     break;
        }
        System.out.println(monthString);
    }
}
```

Comment: OP commented that he doesn't like to use a `switch` statement.

Comment: a bad boilerplate example, an enum with `String`/`int` fields and one static method should replace this mess (I didn't downvote)

Comment: I downvoted, not because of answering with `switch`, but because you copied and pasted the example from the tutorial, rather than give a simplified example or a more relevant example of your own. It seems you saw Fast Snail's post and acted on it, without really putting any thought into your answer. Sorry man. If you fixed up your answer, I'll be more than happy to retract the downvote.

Comment: In this case, an array of strings would be more efficient than a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could adopt 3 approaches, namely :-

1. Using a Hash Map to exploit a  pair type of storage.
2. Using a switch case would be helpful in order to avoid multiple checks in if-else conditions.
3. You could very well exploit the OOP concepts of C++ and use polymorphism too (using multiple children or multiple interfaces).

Comment: Can you explain that a bit more? For 1, show some code that puts a lambda in a hash map? The OP didn't seem to like `switch` statements. For 3, I'm totally stumped what you mean without code.